# How to manage numbering in lineno package?

Tags: classicthesis

I use `classic thesis` for my thesis and I use the `lineno` package in order to present interviews I made. I use the following commands : `\begin{linenumbers}`and `\end{linenumbers}`between each interview. I have 6 interviews. For the moment, the  numbering of the lines is continuous. But I would have a broken one. How could I do that : having the numbering of the lines of my interviews begin from the start for each interview ?

This my MWE :

```
% book example for classicthesis.sty
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{epigraph} 
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage[tight,french]{minitoc}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc,eulerchapternumbers]{../classicthesis} % ,manychapters
%\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
```

\renewcommand\textflush{flushright}

`\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newlength\epitextskip
\pretocmd{\@epitext}{\em}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@epitext}{\em}{}{}
\patchcmd{\epigraph}{\@epitext{#1}\\}{\@epitext{#1}\\[\epitextskip]}{}{}
\makeatother

\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
\setlength\epitextskip{2ex}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{.8\textwidth}

\FrenchFootnotes
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lineno}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}}
\frontmatter

\begin{document}

%   \pagestyle{scrheadings}
%   \manualmark
%   \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage



\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}} 
\setcounter{section}{0}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Annexes}

\chapter{Entretiens cliniques}



\section{Premier entretien}


\begin{linenumbers}
blablablabla
blablablabla
blablabla
blabla

bla
\end{linenumbers}

\begin{linenumbers}
blablablabla
blablablabla
blablabla
blabla

bla
\end{linenumbers}

\end{document}`

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\resetlinenumber`:

```
\begin{linenumbers}
blablablabla
blablablabla
blablabla
blabla

bla
\end{linenumbers}

\resetlinenumber       %%%<--- here
\begin{linenumbers}
blablablabla
blablablabla
blablabla
blabla

bla
\end{linenumbers}
```

[image]